# Ubuntu System Start-up: What command to insert to run java app?

Tags: java, startup, ubuntu-10.10

In Ubuntu 10.10, System/Preferences/Startup Applications, I am trying to add a .jar program. If the program sits in home/john/this-folder/app.jar, what would I put in the command line for it to run on start-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java -jar /home/john/this-folder/app.jar [optional arg if any]
```

- [java - the Java application launcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to include jar in classpath if you java app needs dependecies.
You do that by:
java -jar /yourApp.jar -cp /home/zzz/libs/